# Log4J working locally but not in higher environments

Tags: logging, log4j, websphere-8

I have an issue with the logging working locally creating the file but when I deliver to another environment it is not creating the file, as far as I am aware the directory does have all the required permissions. Note that the same configuration works in websphere 6.1 dev but we are upgrading to websphere 8 and the logging does not seem to work. Could I get a list of the required configuration elements for log4j and if there are any changes to this for websphere 8. We are using a log4j.xml file to configure our logging - I'm assuming something may have changed for websphere 8 as the config work for was6.1.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path=**Runtime**
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web;#system#"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="**JRE**">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Please see the above I noticed that in the was6 version of the app the classpaths are different - I am not completely familiar with classpaths files as yet im new career :). I do notice however that the attributes for both target runtime and JRE are missing - im wondering if anyone could shed some light if this could affect the logging also - we are missing j2ee web container and module container references from the was8 version?

T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

By any chance does any of your code or 3rd-party libraries also use slf4j? If so, we discovered that under WebSphere 8, there's an interaction between, I think, JCL, slf4j, and log4j, that required us to deploy an slf4j-log4j jar with our application. Same application under WebSphere 6.1 did not require this change.

See

- http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html
- http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/06/06/slf4j-logging-with-log4j-and-jcl/

Comment: unfortunately we don't make use of these third party lib's